Find the total score of each players
I have to find each player's scores:
a=[
    {'name': 'Mike', 'score': 10},
    {'name': 'Mike', 'score': 8},
    {'name': 'Mike', 'score': 6},
    {'name': 'John', 'score': 7},
    {'name': 'John', 'score': 8},
    {'name': 'John', 'score': 5},
    {'name': 'John', 'score': 8},
    {'name': 'Tom', 'score': 8},
    {'name': 'Tom', 'score': 9}
]

s={}
for key,value in a:
    if key not in s:
        s[key]=0
    elif key in s:
        s[key]+=value
print(s)

But I didn't get the exact output as a dictionary. Instead, I got an error:
    s[key]+=value
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, so what do you want to ask? It's not clear what you need help with since the error says what the problem is, though I understand if it's unclear for a beginner. Have you looked at what value is? Try printing it out at the top of the loop, like print(f"{key = }; {value = }"). For more, see How to debug small programs by Eric Lippert and How to step through Python code to help debug issues? See also [ask].

a is a list so you want to iterate over items of the list, but each item is a dictionary that you will need to unpack. At the moment almost by chance, key and value happen to be the two keys of each dictionary in a.

You have a list of dictionaries. When you perform for key, value in a:, you are unpacking the keys of each dictionary into key and value, which results in key and value being the 'name' and 'score' strings, respectively.
What you need to do instead is iterate through each item of the list, then get the 'name' and 'score' of each item and add them to the new dictionary:
s = {}
for item in a:
    key = item['name']
    value = item['score']
    if key not in s:
        s[key] = 0
    s[key] += value
print(s)

result:
{'Mike': 24, 'John': 28, 'Tom': 17}


You have a list of dictionaries that you need to enumerate. You can do this with a simple for loop.
You can simplify the handling of your desired result by utilising collections.defaultdict as follows:
from collections import defaultdict

a = [
    {"name": "Mike", "score": 10},
    {"name": "Mike", "score": 8},
    {"name": "Mike", "score": 6},
    {"name": "John", "score": 7},
    {"name": "John", "score": 8},
    {"name": "John", "score": 5},
    {"name": "John", "score": 8},
    {"name": "Tom", "score": 8},
    {"name": "Tom", "score": 9},
]

result = defaultdict(int)

for d in a:
    result[d["name"]] += d["score"]

print(dict(result))

Output:
{'Mike': 24, 'John': 28, 'Tom': 17}

